# Typescript Set Value of Class itself in Method, Inheritance from Base Class

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

How do I set a value of a class itself in its own method? Trying to utilize `this`. Receiving an error below .

```
export class ProductForm extends FormGroup {

    constructor(){
      super({
        productName: new FormControl()
      })
    }
   
    addMoreFieldsTest(): void {
      this = {
        productName: new FormControl(),
        productDescription: new FormControl()
     }
}
```

> Error: The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access.

I could use AddControl method, however want to set class itself for learning purposes.

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't really make sense. [What problem are you actually trying to solve](https://xyproblem.info/) by doing this?

Comment: I want to be able to change the value of class itself, and extend in other cases, this is for business sample

Comment: You cannot do that, as the error message explains. Why do you think you need to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated Answer

The controls of a FormControl do not reside directly on the FormGroup class but inside of a property on the class named `controls`

Therefore, if you merely wish to add to the controls on the extending class you simply need to manipulate the controls property.

```js
    export class ExtendedFormGroup extends FormGroup {
      constructor(
        controls: { [k: string]: AbstractControl },
        validatorOrOpts?: ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions,
        asyncValidator?: AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[]
      ) {
        super({...controls, alwaysPresent: new FormControl()}, 
               validatorOrOpts, 
               asyncValidator
        );
        this.extendedProperties();
      }
    
      extendedProperties() {
        this.controls["additional_control"] = new FormControl("");
      }
    }
```

*The above sample does two things*

- pass the constructor argument into super, and add an additional always present item on the control.
- Manipulate the `controls` property directly as reflected in your original question.

Simply calling `new ExtendedFormGroup({})` would now create a FormGroup with two pre-defined controllers `alwaysPresent` and `additional_control`

#### Old response

Since JavaScript, and therefore TypeScript by extension implement classes in a way that are essentially just labelled blocks with prototypes on them, you can use the square bracket notation to access properties on the `this` scope of your class.

```
    class Parent {
      foo: string;
      constructor(foo: string) {
        this.foo = foo;
      }
    }
    
    class Child extends Parent {
      constructor(foo: string) {
        super(foo);
        this.assignPropertiesDirectly();
      }
    
      assignPropertiesDirectly() {
        this["bar"] = "Creates 'bar' on Child";
        this["foo"] = "overwrites foo with this text";
      }
    }
```

However, this approach is brittle as it not only completely defeats the purpose of using TypeScript in the first place, but it also relies on typing string values for property names, which at best will be a hassle to maintain, and at worst will be error prone.

It sounds to me like your problem may be a good candidate for composition design.

Comment: hi Mikkel,I am not trying to alter the additional/sub properties of the class members, but  theclass itself, it inherits from FormGroup , and I am trying to change the values of FormGroup itself

Comment: I gave points and accepted answer, feel free to thumbs up question also, thanks